# Remove Listener when attached Function has Binding

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2017

Consider the following code:

```
class Test {

    constructor() {
        this.breakpoints = {};
    }

    add(options) {

        // Register the media query
        this.breakpoints[options.breakpoint] = window.matchMedia(options.breakpoint);

        // Register the listener
        this.breakpoints[options.breakpoint].addListener(this.breakpoint.bind(this));

    }

    remove(options) {
        this.breakpoints[options.breakpoint].removeListener(this.breakpoint.bind(this));
    }

    breakpoint() {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

In the above code, you will notice that I am attaching an event listener in the `add` method, and attempting to remove it in the `remove` method. Due to the code in the `breakpoint` method, the `bind(this)` part is absolutely crucial.

As a result of the `bind(this)` (I believe), the `removeListener` is not removing the media query listener. Is there any way to solve this?

I have also tried this (without the `bind` on remove):

```
remove(options) {
    this.breakpoints[options.breakpoint].removeListener(this.breakpoint);
}
```

Comment: an alternative to `this.breakpoint = this.breakpoint.bind(this);` in the constructor is to define the function as an arrow function: `class Test { breakpoint = () => {...} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to bind the `breakpoint` method to the context of the current instance in the constructor, so that referencing `this.breakpoint` always refers to the bound method later:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.breakpoint = this.breakpoint.bind(this);
        this.breakpoints = {};
    }

    add(options) {
        // Register the media query
        this.breakpoints[options.breakpoint] = window.matchMedia(options.breakpoint);

        // Register the listener
        this.breakpoints[options.breakpoint].addListener(this.breakpoint);
    }

    remove(options) {
        this.breakpoints[options.breakpoint].removeListener(this.breakpoint);
    }

    breakpoint() {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure how you managed to answer that so quickly... Tested and works! I would never have figured that out! Thank you very much, really appreciate your help! Will accept the answer once I am able to